# How to configure two local projects in CentOS Apache

Tags: php, apache, centos7

I have two local projects using Apache and CentOS 7.
I would like to run two projects simultaneously.
How to configure apache config?

Comment: I use first project <VirtualHost *:80> and ServerName localhost. I do second project  <VirtualHost *:81> and ServerName localhost:81. It works localhost but doesn't do localhost:81.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can configure two different virtual hosts on the same port but with different server names

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName project1.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/project1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName project2.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/project2
</VirtualHost>
```

then add the following line to your /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 project1.local project2.local
```

then in your browser you should be able to access the two projects on http://project1.local and http://project2.local

Comment: how to call project1.local from another PC?

Comment: Make sure that your system has a ip address which is accessable from the outside and apache is listining on that. Then just change the /etc/hosts to the accessable ip address and install that line on all needed end-devices.

Comment: like eiskaltereistee said, you should add the line to /etc/hosts of other machines but replace 127.0.0.1 with your network accessible IP.

Comment: IP address works only one project. How to make for two projects?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got this assumption 'IP address works only one project.', VirtualHost'ing was created to serve multiple sites using the same IP.
Did you try the above? Are you having any issues?

Comment: I tried the above that project1.local and project2.local are worked within one PC.

Comment: Thank you, It was necessary to configure another PC hosts file    [  ip project1.local project2.local  ].

Comment: if it worked as expected please accept the answer so the question is solved and others can find it more easily.